# Should I use a glossy shader or a metal texture to export an object?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, export

I have a model i wanna sell on CGTrader, and i know some people might be using different software like 3DS Max or Maya, so i want to make my blender model available to all software. one of my objects on the model is using a glossy shader to create a silver look. i don't know if maya has a glossy shader, so would it be smarter to go with something every software has, textures? should i use a metal texture or a glossy shader? which one is applicable to most software? is there a glossy shader in other 3d software?

Comment: Could you please gener generalize your question according to [tour]. (https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour) In that form it will attract downvotes.

Comment: thanks cegatron. i'm just asking if in terms on other 3D software compatibility if i should use a metal texture instead of a glossy shader.

Comment: edited it to further explain my question.

Comment: If you want to have object with shading for some other render engines like Maya, VRay besides Cycles then do materials for Maya, VRay and Cycles. Maps have to be baked as well but that isn't enough to have actual material

Comment: no this is not a duplicate, i am asking if exporting a model with a texture works better for other 3D software besides blender.

Comment: It's not an exact duplicate, but what they mean is: the suggested post should help you to understand that (other than very basic) materials are so much specific of each program that it could make no difference to choose one shader or another. Blender does it in one way, Maya and other programs each will do it differently. My 2c.